# While doing a datafix for around 1k record however I get system violation error after 800 records are processed?

Tags: ewam

I am processing 1k record however I get system violation error after 800 record. Could someone please suggest how can this error be resolved?

Comment: Where's your code? What error are you getting? Please read [Ask]

Answer (score 1):

There are designated methods for using OQL, you should take care to

1. Use a cursor variable
2. Declare a size that makes sense for your query
3. Open the cursor (allocates memory)
4. Close the cursor (disposes memory)

   ```
   procedure ShowMoviesInCategory(theCategory : tCategory)
      var Curs : aOQLCursor 
      var curMovie : aMovie
      Curs = Motor.OpenOQLCursor   
      Curs.BatchSize = 50 
      OQL select * from x in aMovie++ where x.Category = theCategory using Curs   
         forEach curMovie in Curs
            WriteLn(curMovie)
         endFor
      Motor.CloseOQLCursor(Curs)
   endProc
   ```

Please also refer to the eWAM Help under OQL and 
wTECH 101 (week1 - day 5 "101A - OQL - Search.pptx"
In Wynsure there is a designated variable for this, please refer to the **Wynsure Development Rules.docx**